# Visual Studio 2015 Model Project Generic / Template Bindings

Tags: generics, visual-studio-2015, uml, templatebinding

I have the folloing model:
[image]

In the interface "IDocumentationData" I bind the template parameter "TDataClass" from the interface "IDataClass" to "IDocumentationData". That's easy.

Now in the interface "IDataClass" I would have to bind the template parameter TCopy from the interface IDeepCopyable to the binding of TDataClass. 
Somethine like:

> IDataClass : IDeepCopyable<TCopy -> TDataClass>

But sadly thats not possible in Visual Studio at least I was unable to find the correct way. I am only able to bind classes, interfaces, enum,  and so on...

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Kind Regards